# Where can I download the MySQL prefpane source code for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mysql

I have been poking around for a while and I have been unable to find the source code for the MySQL prefPane for Mac.

I found this for PosgreSQL

https://github.com/jwang/pgpane

which is helpful but not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that to get your copy of source code you have to fill in the form here => http://creativeeyes.at/main/240

At least this is how I understand that.....

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried contacting them a while back but no response. I was hoping for a Git repo I could just peruse the code with.